# Creating a Pixmap in LibGDX can't find file

Tags: java, libgdx

This code keeps throwing io.FileNotFoundException:

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
spriteMap = new Texture(new Pixmap(new FileHandle("Sprites.png")));
spriteMap.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest);
spriteMap.setWrap(TextureWrap.ClampToEdge, TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
sprites = new TextureRegion(spriteMap).split(16, 16);
```

any ideas what's wrong? i have also tried `spriteMap = new Texture(new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("Sprites.png")));` but no luck...Sprites.png is just right in the package this class is in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using this:

```
spriteMap = new Texture(new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("Sprites.png")));
```

be totally sure you have a file called **"Sprites.png"** (with the capital 'S') inside your **assets** folder.

```
assets/Sprites.png
```

If you have a folder between, for example **data** (created with the [Libgdx-setup-ui](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar) by default). then you would need to put it aswell.

```
assets/data/Sprites.png
```

If you are sure the file is there. Then:

- If running from eclipse, refresh your project (**f5**), it may be unsynchronized)
- If this only happens in the Desktop project, then maybe your assets folder is not correctly linked.

**Edit:**

You edited your question :p

> Sprites.png is just right in the package this class is in

thats your problem, `Gdx.files.internal` looks into the Android **assets** folder. not the folder in which the class is in.

Comment: I don't have an assets folder...do I just make one? I didn't use Libgdx-setup-ui

Comment: you aren't using an Android project?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that...this is just the Desktop project. I'm not using an Android project

Comment: Then create any folder inside your Desktop project root, for example "data" and use it like this "data/Sprites.png" internal looks also in the project root

Comment: Worked great! Thanks a lot for your help. Just curious, since I am creating the texture in my Main project, why does adding the png to a folder in my Desktop project work?

Comment: Because the project that you are running is the Desktop one, and that uses the main project (**core project** as we call it). The Core project isnt runnable :) if the answer helped you, dont forget to accept it thanks :D

Comment: I had the same Problem. The folder you use for Desktop has to be marked as a sourcefolder to use it with gdx.files.internal. Do not forget this. Also the gdx.files.internal is automatically in your source folder. So if you use a source folder named sources you don't need to call gdx.files.internal("sources/yourpath").

Comment: To add onto @Springrbua's comment, in IntelliJ you can mark the folder as a Resources folder (under Project Structure) and then provide paths relative to that folder to libgdx, i.e. create an assets folder, mark is as Resources, put foo.txt in it, then use Gdx.files.internal("foo.txt");.